# Remove consecutive duplicate comma in a text file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a text file name file.txt contains

```
remo/hello/1.0,remo/hello2/2.0,,remo/hello3/3.0,whitney/hello/1.0,,,julie/hello/2.0,,,,remo/hello2/2.0,,remo/hello3/3.0,,
```

i want to delete the consecutive duplicate commas(,) in the file say after deleting the output file should be like this

output.txt

```
remo/hello/1.0,remo/hello2/2.0,remo/hello3/3.0,whitney/hello/1.0,julie/hello/2.0,remo/hello2/2.0,remo/hello3/3.0,
```

i have tried below code:

```
awk '!seen[$0]++' filename
```

but didn't work out.

Please help TIA.

Comment: That snippet is for deleting duplicate lines not characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `tr` to "squeeze" consecutive commas

```
tr -s , <input >output
```

Comment: @RajMullapu, tr is translate utility that is a common tool installed on most common *nix systems. Try *man tr* on your system to see if it's available. By the way, tr is the fastest of them all for such substitutions.

Comment: @RajMullapu yeah, `tr` is a classic bash utility.

Comment: @glennjackman that's also true, and out of the context of "will this work in bash" it's probably *more* true, but I was trying to respond to raj

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sed` for this:

`sed -r "s/,{2,}/,/g" filename`

Comment: You need `-r` to enable un-escaped braces (or escape the braces)
, and you'll want the `g` modifier to replace all matches

Comment: @glennjackman thanks, forgot about the global. But it works fine without `-r` for me (CentOS, GNU Sed 4.2.2), what's up with that, I wonder.